# SoapUI Groovy Scripts

Tags: groovy, mocking, soapui, groovy-console

I'm trying to read the incoming request & set the mock response depending on a value comming in the request in `soapUI 3.0`. I use the following groovy script for this.

```
def typeElement = mockRequest.getContentElement().execQuery("//ProductType");
def records =  new XmlParser().parseText(typeElement[0].xmlText())
if (records.text()=="15"){
    mockOperation.setDefaultResponse("Response 2");
} else {
    mockOperation.setDefaultResponse("Response 1");
}
```

But it does not work, complaining that `mockRequest` object is null:

> com.eviware.soapui.impl.wsdl.mock.DispatchException: Failed to dispatch using script; java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke method getContentElement() on null object

but I've used similar kind of code with `soapUI 2.0` version and was successful. How can I fix this?

Answer (score 2):

I know this question is pretty old, but I came across the same problem yesterday and here's how I managed to dispatch responses using groovy script (please note, this is the first time I used both soapUI and groovy, thus probably there will be better ways to do that).

```
    // define request
    def request = new XmlSlurper().parseText(mockRequest.requestContent);
    def resultingResponse = "none"

    //when missing password
    def Password = request.Body.CreateUser.user.Password
    if(Password == '') {
        resultingResponse = 'MissingPassword'
    }

    //when missing firstname
    def Firstname = request.Body.CreateUser.user.FirstName
    if(Firstname == '') {
        resultingResponse = 'MissingFirstname'
    }

context.ResultResponse = resultingResponse
```

Answer (score 2):

Again, I appreciate this is old, but Sinnerinc's answer above doesn't solve the original problem, because his solution will still suffer from a NPE because mockRequest was null.

I have a related issue, and found [this post](https://community.smartbear.com/t5/SoapUI-Open-Source/SoapUI-5-2-1-mockRequest-is-NULL-in-REST-MockService/m-p/179676/highlight/true#M28382) which suggests the mockResponse will be null if the mock service has never served a request and you click on the green triangle button to run the script!

Answer (score 0):

In the [SmartBear Forum](https://community.smartbear.com/t5/SoapUI-Open-Source/SoapUI-5-2-1-mockRequest-is-NULL-in-REST-MockService/td-p/118216) solution code, the green 'play' button pops up the 'mockRequest is Null' warning, because the mock request object is not def'd up.

The mockRequest object is defined when a 'real' test executes the MockService endpoint.

To test code I put the following Test Code and click 'play' until I am happy with my coverage.

Then I send a Test Step to call the MockService endpoint

Here is the code:

```
def mockRequestrequestContent = "" 
if (mockRequest != null) 
    mockRequestrequestContent = mockRequest.requestContent
else 
    mockRequestrequestContent = "<testRequestXmlOrJson/>" 
log.info(mockRequestrequestContent) 

//begin script like @sinnerinc's above
```

Note: The current version of SoapUI 5.50 doesn't have a log window at the bottom, trying to gather information is challenging.